# What are the specifications for 3D animated game assets on the Android platform?

Tags: android, efficiency

(apologies if this is phrased vaguely due to my lack of knowledge; I'm happy to change the question entirely if someone can suggest a more realistic query)

I'm getting a grip on creating 3D characters in Lightwave, Maya, Blender, etc. My goal is to focus on creating creature & character animations specifically for games. I thought it would be a good exercise to make a few critters with a specific scope. As a non-programmer (I've written a few scripts, but I really don't have a passion to code) - can you point me in the right direction to find some guidelines? (I have a programmer handy who will write the code, but I want to be able to give him assets that are as usable as possible)

I assume that Android games are intended to run on limited hardware - maybe there's a polycount I should shoot for, or a particular memory limit? The resources I've found so far all seem to be [helpful to developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html) - haven't found much oriented in my direction

Answer (score 1):

This question really depends on what game you are targeting.  It's very specific to the engine and platform.  So, that would be more of a question for your programmer buddy than anyone.  Is it his own game engine or 3rd party?  Either way, he should know A) the formats used or preferred and B) the "requirements" of the system and C) any special cases such as max polygon count, textures sizes/foramts,  animations, etc.

Generally speaking, you will want to work with whatever format that works best for you (as the artist).  Once you have a finished model, you'll want to give that to your development team.  They will compile that offline into an optimized format/textures that works best with their engine.